# HTML - Create a responsive top-navitaion menu over a background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently designing my webpage (in which I am pretty unexperienced), and I am stuck in one sensitive part. I was using so far a template from HTML Up, but it does not come with a menu on top.

I would like to have a **menu** like this one: [Goal](https://html5up.net/landed)
This is my current webpage: [Github Page](https://edualvarado.github.io/) and the Github repo where the page is: [Repo](https://github.com/edualvarado/edualvarado.github.io)

This is what I tried so far. In the `index.html` I have the following for the `header` (the `nav` part is what I added).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Eduardo Alvarado</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
  </head>
  <body class="is-preload">
    
    <!-- Header -->
      <section id="header">
        <!-- Nav -->
          <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Research</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Game-dev</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Photography</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        
        <!-- -->
        
        <div class="inner">
          <span><img src="/images/car_final_256_header.gif"></span>
          <h1>Hi, I'm <strong>Eduardo Alvarado</strong>.</h1>
          <h1>A passionate software engineer who develops intelligent<br />
          cars during the day and loves to design<br />
          game-focus art and applications in his spare-time.</h1>
          <br />
          <p>Want to contact me? Send me a message at <a href="mailto:alvaradopinero.eduardo@gmail.com">alvaradopinero.eduardo@gmail.com</a>.</p>
          <ul class="actions special">
            <li><a href="#one" class="button scrolly">Discover</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Nevertheless, I am not sure about the `.css` and how it should look like. I already tried this tutorial: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp), but I cannot make it transparent. It is like if it creates its own "space" and does not overlay over the background.

Could you please guide me on this of recommend me some link or source about how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you write your existing website? If so, I am confused about the pitch of your question. It seems to be from the point of view of a beginner but the website looks pretty clean. If you want to learn, I would highly recommend familiarising yourself with developers tools, so you can see the effect of various stylings in real time. You can view the styling of online websites and see the effects of removing/adding elements. It accelerated my CSS learning.

Comment: Thank you! I have used a template although I modified some parts. I am not familiarised with HTML/CSS however, but with Python and C++, so I consider myself a beginning although I know how to program. Would you have a hint/link to an HTML code that achieves what I am trying for? Thank you!

Comment: What is preventing you from copying the code from the example page? It's all there for the taking..

Answer (score 1):

CSS styles are missing in `<section>` ,`<nav>` and its child elements. Developers usually check CSS styles either by right-clicking on specific DOM element in the browser and then choosing to inspect element or by pressing F12. I have compared styles for these tags. I have compared styles for these tags between two repositories.

[image]

It is clear from above image that, few styles are missing from CSS file. There are so many changes to be done in CSS file which stackoverflow is not the correct place to show the corrections.

There are so many learning resources available over internet to learn CSS like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) with lot of examples like creating menu bar, etc. Happy learning.